# Skype for Business online WebSDK sign in

Tags: skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I'm trying to use Skype for Business online WebSDK. I'm following the instructions located here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/Skype/WebSDK/docs/DevelopWebSDKappsForSfBOnline.
I'm trying to authenticate user with Office 65 online but I have problems while executing app.signInManager.signIn command.
Browser sends several requests:

1. Request URL:https://webdir.online.lync.com/autodiscover/autodiscoverservice.svc/root
   Request Method:GET
   Status Code:200 OK
2. Request URL:https://webdir2e.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root/oauth/user
   Request Method:OPTIONS
   Status Code:200 OK
3. Request URL:https://webdir2e.online.lync.com/Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root/oauth/user
   Request Method:GET
   Status Code:401 Unauthorized

The last request is failing with an error:
401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

I'm authenticating with admin user and with an account that has Skype for Business online subscription.

Can you help me with this problem? What am I doing wrong? Are there any other prerequisites to be able to successfully log in?

Comment: Are you passing the correct client id in the sign in method? Verify your client id is correct

Comment: Yes, I'm sure I am passing the correct client id. In case of passing incorrect client id the responce says there is no such application in the domain. I think it is related to some subscription I don't have.

Comment: Is your Office 365 Active Directory synced with the Azure Active Directory where your app is registered? You also should check whether you have provided Skype For Business Online access to your app registered on Azure.

Comment: I'm not sure if my Office 365 AD is synced with the Azure AD. I don't see how to do that in this guide - https://msdn.microsoft.com/Skype/WebSDK/docs/DevelopWebSDKappsForSfBOnline. Can you tell me how I can check if the synchronization is on? Is it somehow related to the Azure AD Connect?
I have provided Skype For Business Online access to my app. If I understood correctly it is Tenant Administrator Consent Flow.

Comment: The same issue while trying this simple example - https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-web-sdk-simple-sample-for-SfB-online. There is an issue identical to mine described here - https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-web-sdk-simple-sample-for-SfB-online/issues/2.

Comment: If you Office 365 AD is synced with Azure AD, then after you login into you Azure, you should be able to see 2 AD's. You should also be able to see the users of Office 365 visible under the AD in Azure. Then you should check if you have registered an app in the Azure Ad linked to Office 365 and granted permissions to it.

Comment: Ok. I did everything from scratch this time following the guide here https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-web-sdk-simple-sample-for-SfB-online. Created a Microsoft account, got a free O365 tenant, signed up for free Azure Active Directory trial account. Associated my O365 account with Azure AD as described here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/setup-development-environment#associate-your-office-365-account-with-azure-ad-to-create-and-manage-apps. Then I registered the new app in Azure Active Directory to use Skype for Business.

Comment: Then I updated config.js in the skype web sdk simple sample for SfB online application.
And again no luck, the same error - 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.

Comment: But after some more investigation I finally found a cause of the issue. I will describe it in the answer to my question.

Comment: @Shahzad, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did everything from scratch following the guide here https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-web-sdk-simple-sample-for-SfB-online. Created a Microsoft account, got a free O365 tenant, signed up for free Azure Active Directory trial account. Associated my O365 account with Azure AD as described here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/setup-development-environment#associate-your-office-365-account-with-azure-ad-to-create-and-manage-apps. Then I registered the new app in Azure Active Directory to use Skype for Business.
Then I updated config.js in the skype web sdk simple sample for SfB online application.
And again no luck, the same error - 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.

I was trying to run the index.html page on the localhost in the htdocs/skype directory. Of course I was setting the reply url accordinly as http://localhost/skype/index.html.
Then I tried to move everything in skype directory to the root - to the htdocs folder. And also changed reply url to http://localhost/index.html. And very strangly but it helped. Now I can successfully login using Skype WebSDK.
I don't know the reason for why it is working only this way. If someone have an idea you are welcome to comment.

Comment: wow... that was not the answer I was looking for.. So will the problem I've been dealing with for 2 days be solved just like this? Heh, Microsoft... You're playing with us..